# How can I broadcast Avahi services between Vagrant (VirtualBox) VMs?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant, zeroconf, avahi

I've got a project with a Vagrantfile which takes a while downloading all its Debian packages.  I figured an easy way to speed up initial provisioning would be to make another Vagrant-based project with just `squid-deb-proxy`.

I made a Vagrantfile, and a simple bootstrap.sh that installs that package (and `avahi-utils`).  I've mapped guest port 8000 to host port 8000.  I've confirmed that I can telnet to it from my host machine, and also from other VMs (as 10.0.2.2:8000, the host address).  I've confirmed (with `avahi-browse -a` on the squid-deb-proxy VM) that it's broadcasting its presence.

The only piece remaining is to get *other* VMs to see its zeroconf service broadcasts.  Zeroconf seems to use port 5353, but I can't map guest 5353 to host 5353 (the host is already using that), and if I map guest 5353 to host something else, the broadcast isn't seen.

I've connected multiple Vagrant projects using "private networking" before, but I don't want to do that here, since it would require all my other projects to know about my squid-deb-proxy VM.

Is there an easy way to do what I want here?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to cache Debian packages is to install the [vagrant-cachier](http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier/) plugin.

If you want to use a caching proxy, you can easily configure other Vagrant guests to use it with the [vagrant-proxyconf](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf) plugin. If you add the configuration globally to `$HOME/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile` you don't need to pollute individual Vagrant projects.